# Algebraic Sequences, mortgage geometric sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series

selma has a mortgage of 150000. At the end of each year 6% interest is added before Selma pays 10000.

Q) Find an expression for how much is owed at the end of the nth year?!

Comment: what has been tried ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) What is the recurrence relation? i.e. if $x_{n}$ is owed at the end of the $n$th year, with $x_{0}=150000$, what is $x_{n+1}$ in terms of $x_{n}$? You should be able to work this out.

> It's $x_{n+1}=1.06x_{n}-10000$.

2) Can you use this to come up with a closed form expression for $x_{n}$?

Hint 1:

> Try $x_{n}=a\cdot1.06^{n}+c$. Substitute into the recurrence relation and then substitute in $x_{0}$ to get the two constants.

Answer:

> $x_{n+1} = 1.06x_{n}-10000 = 1.06\cdot a\cdot1.06^{n}+1.06c - 10000 = a\cdot1.06^{n+1}+1.06c-10000 = a\cdot1.06^{n+1}+c \Rightarrow 0.06c = 10000 = 10^{6}/6 \\ x_{0}= 150000 = a + 10^{6}/6 \Rightarrow a = (900000-10^{6})/6 = -10^{5}/6 \\ \therefore x_{n} = \frac{10^{5}}{6}\left(10 - 1.06^{n}\right)$
> You can find the number of years to pay the mortgage by finding the smallest integer $n$ for which $x_{n}\le 0$, which is $\lceil\ln{10}/\ln{1.06}\rceil = 40$.

Answer (score 0):

Make up the difference equation:
$$y_{n+1}=1.06y_n-10,000, \ \ y_0=150,000.$$
Its solution is:
$$y_n=-16,666.67\cdot 1.06^n+166,666.67.$$

Answer (score 0):

The future value of the payments after the $n$th payment is

$$FV = \frac{pmt}{i} \left[(1+i)^n-1\right]$$

The mortgage has a present value of $150\ 000$, which has a future value of $$150\ 000(1+i)^n$$

So the difference will be

$$150\ 000\cdot 1.06^n - \frac{10\ 000}{0.06} (1.06^n - 1)$$